# External drive not recognized

Tags: partitioning, windows

I have a 500gb external drive that I used for Windows storage. Later, I partitioned it and made an Ubuntu partition. Now, when I connect the HDD on Windows, it is not able to recognize it, but Ubuntu can see all the data. Is there any way that I can fix it so that Windows sees the windows partition at least on Win XP? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

If the drive is formatted to ext4 or ext3, Windows cannot detect it. Format using FAT file system instead.

Comment: NTFS should work also

Comment: Yaa.. NTFS too!

Answer (score 0):

You can use a tool like [ext2fsd](http://www.ext2fsd.com/) to mount the drive on Windows. Be careful though - the support for ext3/4 on Windows is not as robust, and writing to the drive may corrupt it, so you're best off mounting in read-only mode. There's a nice guide on how to use it [here](http://www.webupd8.org/2011/08/access-ext4-ext3-or-ext2-partitions-in.html).